# HUP not the same as restarting a service/daemon?

Tags: unix

So, in studying for the LPI Certification, and doing some practice exams, I keep running into questions that I get wrong simply because I assume the HUP signal is equivalent to restarting a service/daemon. Obviously, I'm wrong, but can someone enlighten me as to why?

The Apache documentation states that HUP kill off the process' children, but not the parent, which sense, but is this behaviour mimicked in unix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual effect of `HUP` on long-running daemons is to reload the configuration. Sometimes this is done by restarting completely, sometimes something more intelligent/fast/safe is done.

There is nothing mandatory about this behavior, it's not really what that signal was intended for originally. (The [SIGHUP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP) article on Wikipedia has a bit more details.)

Each daemon's writer is free to implement `SIGHUP` handling as he/she wishes. This includes ignoring the signal entirely.